# Converting properties first letter of each word to uppercase

Tags: javascript, java

We have a feed that reals in product information, such as SKU, product name etc.

We're having an issue where the first letter of each word for the product name isn't being capitalised. I'm only able to capitalise the entire string rather than the first letter of each word.

We're using Fresca Commerce if it helps.

```
#set ($product = $information.getRequestAttribute('product').getAttributesValue("PLU_DESCRIPTION").toUpperCase())
```

And the data is coming from a Json array

```
FitsMeData = {
  Id : "${sku}",
  ProductTitle : "${product}",
  ProductCategories : ['${fm}'],
  ProductImageUrl : "/pws/images/catalogue/products/${sku}/zoom/${sku}.jpg",
  Sizes : sizes
}
```

I've tried selecting the first characters, converting toString and then toUpperCase but it causes the product page to not even display.

Comment: You need solution in JavaScript or Java? JavaScript !== Java

Comment: and java.equals(javaScript) == false

Comment: JavaScript or Java works fine. I have next to no knowledge of Java though. Whatever gets it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ucwords(str) {

  return (str + '')
    .replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
      return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

refrrence - http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords/